# How to give a magic variable to a script in Bash

Tags: bash

How to give a magic variable (placeholder) to a script?

Let's have a `loop` script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

count=$1
shift

for i in $(seq 1 $count)
do
    $*
done
```

I want to call it like that:

`loop 5 echo Mambo number $i`

However, Bash expands the variable before the script call and produces:

```
Mambo number
Mambo number
Mambo number
Mambo number
Mambo number
```

If I call it like that:

`loop 5 echo Mambo number '$i'`

the variable is not expanded within the script

```
Mambo number $i
Mambo number $i
Mambo number $i
Mambo number $i
Mambo number $i
```

Is there a clever way to use a magic variable in bash?

I want to achieve:

```
Mambo number 1
Mambo number 2
Mambo number 3
Mambo number 4
Mambo number 5
```

And also:

`loop 3 touch 'foo-$i.log'`

To create three files:

```
foo-1.log
foo-2.log
foo-3.log
```

Comment: `seq 1 5 | xargs -n1 echo Mambo number` would do for you?

Comment: Do you mean just to pass a variable to a script by it's name? Or to pass more complex expressions to be evaluated into the script environment.

Comment: @thanasisp, I first wanted to experiment with a variable only. However, `loop 5 echo $i + $i = $((i + i))` whout be the best :)

Comment: If you want to pass a variable by name reference, look for Bash 4.2+ **nameref** type variable declared `declare -n namerefvar`, or some more geunine indrection `${!varname}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to eval your arguments

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
count=$1
shift
    
for i in $(seq 1 $count)
do
    eval "$@"
done
```

you have to protect any variables to be expanded later

```
bash loop.sh 3 echo test '"$i"'
test 1
test 2
test 3
```

or better protect the whole string in single quotes to be one string argument

```
bash loop.sh 3 'echo "$i" "$((i+1))"  $(bc -l <<< "$i+2")'
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

and carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to delay the evaluation of a variable (do "lazy evaluation") in bash.

1. with the `${!varname}` "indirect expansion" form, which is not portable to other shells
2. with `eval`, which is portable, and more versatile and obvious, but will get you into trouble with some, huh, less-than-ideal people examining your code ;-)

So, I'll give a possible solution with the first.

```
loop(){
   local i cnt=$1 cmd=$2 arg=$3
   for((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do "$cmd" "${!arg}"; done 
}
mambo(){
   printf '%s ' mambo nr "$@"; echo
}
loop 6 mambo i
mambo nr 0
mambo nr 1
mambo nr 2
mambo nr 3
mambo nr 4
mambo nr 5
```